# eval not working after using horzcat matlab

Tags: matlab, eval

im trying to make a script to be able to calculate a vector of numbers and math symbols to convert back to a single string

im using eval() function and example would be

```
str = '4*2'
eval(str)
```

and the result would be

```
ans =

8
```

but when i create into a vector and convert back using horzcat the result won't work.

```
Number = [52    42    50]
Number1 = (mat2str(char(Number)))
str = horzcat(Number1)
eval(str)
```

and i would get

```
ans =

4*2
```

can anyone help me find the problem with the script?

Comment: Why do you use `eval` at all? This it a very bad practice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with the `mat2str` command. This is unecesarry. The `char` command already returns a string. You end up with a string in a string, so when you `eval` in your code, you just display the inner string.

Comment: thank you very much i was trying to randomize the math symbol but couldnt' figure out how to convert it back to the string and calculate. I thought 'char' didn't return string yet and prob added 'mat2str' command.

Answer (score 0):

First - You should not use `eval`!

Second, there is no need in `horzcat` and `mat2str` in your code. Just write:

```
str = char(Number)
```